# Changing XML filename for Google Calendar sidebar gadget that uses osapi.http causes RPCs to return 401 errors

Tags: google-calendar-api, google-oauth, google-gadget, apache-shindig

For an html type google gadget with module pref:

```
<Require feature="osapi" />
```

initially defined in file gadget1.xml, it will properly execute RPCs. However, if you remove it from your calendar, change its filename to gadget2.xml and then add gadget2.xml to your calendar, you'll get 401 errors with description:

> Malformed security token e=AEY54zciGYGPUeNVsaxlD19nATK4jqm6LqusewGP%2FFg4ILfkGu5bSh3ThxITog%2B3m6FVSy2HsVToSyQGDzXQxBgpM5LF%2F%2BRaw2FOswxfdpgm7GgK0zpGyC9BRI1KCsURqZM0%2F%2FYLhnEN&c=calendar
>   com.google.gadgets.auth.AuthTokenException: com.google.gadgets.gaia.GaiaConverterException: 
>   Request for GaiaClientConst::INVALID_USERID

The RPC call doesn't require any additional authorization beyond Google Calendar's default Add Gadget dialog and this problem occurs even when any prior authorizations have been removed via https://myaccount.google.com/security#connectedapps. What does user ID refer to and how to change it?

Comment: It might be caused by the Google implementation (Gaia?) of Apache Shindig's OAuthLookupService.php. Follow up: is there caching that needs to be cleared?